# How to read size of a pbm file in ASCII mode?

Tags: image, python-2.7, file

Let us consider the example:

The pbm file "imFile.pbm" contains the pixels as follows :

```
P1
# Comment
9 6
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I determine the width and Height of the image.   I have used the following code but failed.

```
 with open("imFile.pbm", 'rb') as f:
    image = f.size
    print image
    f.close()
```

When I compiled it in my ubuntu14.04 os, it shows error. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The width and height is right there in the file, in the first row after the first one, skipping comments. That's not what `.size` is for; you need to read and parse the file.

Comment: @Amadan-- How can I do this? Can you explain me plese?

Answer (score 0):

> The width and height is right there in the file, in the first row after the first one, skipping comments. That's not what .size is for; you need to read and parse the file.

```
with open("imFile.pbm", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines.pop(0)                       # skip header
line = lines.pop(0)                # get next line
while line.startswith("#"):        # repeat till that line is not a comment
    line = lines.pop(0)
width, height= line.split()        # split the first non-comment lin
print("%s x %s" % (width, height)) # => 9 x 6
```